# admin bare notification counter

Tags: support, moderation

I want to know what is the meaning of the counter (orange) shown in the top bar. I thought it was for the unreviewed posts but it seems not, because  sometimes there is no post to review and i get 9/8..

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked that very same question on another meta a while ago...

https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1166/4376

The answer seems to be that the number doesn't necessarily correspond to the number of reviews outstanding.  It just indicates that there *are* reviews outstanding.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing. it's a global counter.