# Why low quality posts queue option in the review queues drop-down has a red dot even the queue is cleared?

Tags: discussion, bug, reviews

Most of the time I have seen the low quality posts in the review queues drop-down  has a red dot left to it, probably indicating the queue is needed to be cleared urgently. But when I go to the review queue there's no post actually. But I have seen the same red dot near other queues as well, but rarely, and when I visit there's actually a considerable amount of posts.

Is this a bug or what's the explanation for this behavior?

**UPDATE 1**: Happened the same with Suggested Edits queue. Cleared the queue. Refreshed the page. Clicked on the Review queues icon. And this is how it looked.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**: Happened with Close votes queue as well

[image]

Comment: maybe you mean this issue 
 https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396/admin-bare-notification-counter

Comment: it looks related, but the red dot is still there even the queue is cleared, and this only for low quality posts queue, and not just a one day I have seen it may times

Comment: I've seen the same thing and couldn't work it out... I didn't look into it any further. Interested in the answer :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is operating as designed.

The operation of the review queue icons is explained in the main meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/236563).

The icon in your screenshots indicates that there are reviews in the queue awaiting someone's attention.

When you go to the review page, you see the number of reviews available *to you*.
So, if you have skipped a review, or if a review needs two reviewers, the icon will indicate that there are reviews (still) in the queue but they are not available to you.

Comment: your answer is acceptable but the design you explained quite odd, if the review queue is empty for me and the available reviews are for other users attention what's the point of indicating it to me? I think this should be considered as a UX improvement. Is this design only in ethereum stack exchange or in all sites?

Comment: I agree it isn't the most intuitive of presentations.  I wouldn't be surprised if an update was rolled out in due course.